# string interpolation in devise flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, flash-message

I'm new to RoR and I would like to personalise the Devise flash messages to use the name of the current user.

I've seen that the original file includes the following line:

***devise.en.yml***

```
  failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
```

So I've applied the same rule to:

```
sessions:
  signed_in: "Welcome back!."
  signed_out: "See you soon!."
```

-

```
sessions:
  signed_in: "Welcome back! \"#{current_user.first_name}\"."
  signed_out: "See you soon! \"#{current_user.first_name}\"."
```

but the code is not executing, and prints the whole sentence as string.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
sessions:
  signed_in: "Welcome back! %{name}."
  signed_out: "See you soon! %{name}."
```

And you must call it like:

```
t('sessions.signed_in', name: current_user.first_name)
t('sessions.signed_out', name: current_user.first_name)
```

You can't use ruby interpolation in `yml` file but you can pass variable to the `translation` and use `yml` interpolation syntax `%{}`